# My code of a coin game but can't seem to figure out this part

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    alert("Welcome to the coin flip game ! Enter either heads or tails..");

    var person = prompt("Please enter either heads or tails");

    if (person == heads) {
        alert()
    }

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;


    if (random == 1) {
        alert("The computer generated heads!");
    } else {
        alert("The computer generated tails!");
    }
    
    var lost = 
    alert("You've lost");
    
    var won = 
    alert("You've won!");

    if (person != random) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        (lost);
    } else {
        (won);
    }
    



</script>





</body>
</html>
```

My current code ^^

The goal:
Introduce the game and explain how to play.
Receive input from the user, specifically their guess of whether the coin will be heads or tails.
Generate a random number between 1 or 2 and then match that with heads or tails. (ie. 1 = heads, 2 = tails)
Check if their guess matched the random number.
If they guess correctly, tell them they’ve won.
If the guess incorrectly, tell them they’ve lost.

I can't seem to figure out how to assign the turn the 1 and 2 of the random number generator to heads or tails though. That's my big problem.

This is html javascript.

Comment: You're never comparing the user's guess with the random number.

Comment: What's the point of `if (person == heads)`? You need to compare with a string, you don't have a variable named `heads`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of minor logical issues in the code.

1. When the player enters either heads or tails, this can be translated to 1 or 2 in the code for easier comparison with the randomly generated value.
2. If the player enters a junk value this should be handled.
3. I'm not sure I understood what the code to display the result was doing so have just changed it to show an alert with won or lost.

Here's a working snippet showing this in action:

```js
alert("Welcome to the coin flip game ! Enter either heads or tails..");

var person = prompt("Please enter either heads or tails");

var personChoice = 0;
if (person == 'heads') {
    personChoice = 1;
} else if (person == 'tails') {
    personChoice = 2;
} else {
    alert('The player entered rubbish!');
}

if (personChoice > 0) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;

  if (random == 1) {
    alert("The computer generated heads!");
  } else {
    alert("The computer generated tails!");
  }

  var lost = "You've lost";
  var won = "You've won";

  if (personChoice != random) {
   alert(lost); //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (lost);
  } else {
    alert(won);
  //(won);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, Assuming if user keyed other than `heads` considered as `tails`, Note that person == heads, need to comparison with value instead of undeclared variable. Also many typo like

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        (lost);

 (won);
```

```js
alert("Welcome to the coin flip game ! Enter either heads or tails..");

var person = prompt("Please enter either heads or tails");


var userChoice = person === "heads" ? 1 : 2

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;


if (random == 1) {
  alert("The computer generated heads!");
} else {
  alert("The computer generated tails!");
}


if (userChoice != random) {
  alert("You've lost")
} else {
  alert("You've won!")
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" />
```